# How do I display https instead of http in url bar after using SSL on my site

Tags: https, satchmo

I have SSL on my website but in the top URL bar still only says `http://` not `https://`.

I am using the Satchmo system with a Django Python stack for my website. Does anyone have some insight to this?

Comment: Not sure if this helps.  If this were running on IIS, I would check my bindings.  Be sure that SSL is bound to port 443, not 80, and ensure "Force SSL" is checked in the site properties.

Comment: You need to redirect `http://` requests to `https://`.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the web-server being used, you need to tell the client to go to your secure (`https`) site.

They are different protocols, `http` and `https`. If you want the client's browser to use the `https` version of your website you will need to issue a redirect. e.g.:

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com HTTP/1.1


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://stackoverflow.com
```

You'll have to find the mechanism in your web-server code to trigger a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. in my httpd.conf file i added this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about-us
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

where "about-us" was is the url of the page you want to display https